# Dishwasher and hand washing water consumption data

Tags: data-request

There are some blogs and dishwasher manufacturers that say that handwashing of dishes can be between 3.5 and 5 more water-consuming than using a dishwasher. I would like to know if there is some open data to back such statement.

The closest I have been to data is [this page in reviewed](https://www.reviewed.com/dishwashers/features/please-stop-hand-washing-your-dishes), but it's not clear how many cases were analyzed. I am particularly intrigued by the variability I expect in hand washing (machine washing being pretty stable). In [another page](https://www.reviewed.com/dishwashers/features/why-obamas-dishwasher-efficiency-crusade-makes-sense) they say that they followed AHAM's "standardized testing methodology".

I would appreciate if you could lead me towards an open database of water consumption for either (ideally both) hand or machine dishwashing.